# Python while loop keeps repeating itself

Tags: python-3.x

Simple question but it is driving me nuts. why when I run this code does it just keep repeating itself?  And my indentations are correct just had to space 4 times to post this for whatever reason.

High Scores

0 - Exit
    1 - Show Scores

Source code:

```
scores = []

choice = None
while choice != "0":

print(
"""
High Scores

0 - Exit
1 - Show Scores
"""
)

choice = input("choice: ")
print()

if choice == "0":
print ("exiting")

elif choice == "1":
score = int(input("what score did you get?: "))
scores.append(score)

else:
print ("no")

input ("\n\nPress enter to exit")
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're running Python 3?

Comment: sayan 98 is was my identation under my while loop. thank you

Comment: @JacobMoore happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using proper indentation. Please indent the code under the while loop that you want to execute `while choice != 0`

Further there is no mistake with comparison as @wookie919 wrongly indicated because you're taking a String as input and not an Int. You can however typecast your input as a string by wrapping it around an int() like `int(input("Choice .. "))`

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are comparing an Integer to a String. Try entering `"0"` instead of just `0`. Or modify your program to compare with `0` instead of `"0"`.

Comment: Where is OP comparing an int to a string?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's an educated guess after trying OP's code.